# django-daterange-filter ugly display at admin panel

Tags: python, django, datepicker, custom-controls, admin

I have installed django-daterange-filter to my django project and I used it in admin

```
list_filter = [('start_time', DateRangeFilter), 'event_type', ]
```

But it displays ugly, I mean, the date-picker does not appear on the site, but on the right side of page, so I need to scroll page:
[image]

As you can see it is not very useful, I need to scroll page to the right. So I can do 2 things. Move date-picker to the left (but actually I always thought it automatically choose side to display itself) or move filter column from right to left side of panel. I do not know how to do any of them. Moreover how to override "From date" and "To date". It is interesting, because rest of the text is in polish, as language is set at settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

nvm I found answer, but it is hack anyway, not what I wanted really
I changed in file /static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js in function openCalendar so it display more to the left